# Convert SQL Server query to Hive query

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to convert this query:

```
select 
    a.id, a.name, b.math, b.english, b.draw, b.computer 
from
    ek.student a
cross apply 
    (values
         (math_1, english_1, draw_1, computer_1),
         (math_2, english_2, draw_2, computer_2),
         (math_3, english_3, draw_3, computer_3),
         (math_4, english_4, draw_4, computer_4),
         (math_5, english_5, draw_5, computer_5),
         (math_6, english_6, draw_6, computer_6)
     ) b (math, english, draw, computer)
```

from SQL Server into a Hive query.

We do not want to export data to SQL Server and then run that query, we want to directly run query in Hive but we do not know how.

Comment: Only tag the database you want a solution in. And I recommend  providing sample data and desired results rather than just a query to translate.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
     a.id,
     a.name,
     b.math,
     b.english,
     b.draw,
     b.computer 
FROM 
    student a
LATERAL VIEW stack (6,
    math_1, english_1, draw_1, computer_1,
    math_2, english_2, draw_2, computer_2,
    math_3, english_3, draw_3, computer_3,
    math_4, english_4, draw_4, computer_4,
    math_5, english_5, draw_5, computer_5,
    math_6, english_6, draw_6, computer_6
) b as math, english, draw, computer
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `Lateral View` instead of `cross apply`